# how to add classes to build path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used the folllowing steps to add classes to my build path still i am geting errors as import  not resolved.I had followed the following steps.

1. Select Create New Folder and name it
   TpmWebUIClasses.
2. Click the Advanced >> button and
   select the Link to folder in the
   file system check box.
3. Browse for to the folder where you
   have copied the classes
4. Make sure the selected folder is
   listed and then click OK.

How can i resolve the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Right click your project > Properties > Java build path > Libraries > Add Class Folder

But it is much better to package these classes as a `.jar` and add it with `Add JARs` from the same screen. Another way is to make one project depend on another (whose classes are those in question).

Now, if you mean `.java` files rather than `.class` files, you just add a `Source` folder from the first tab on the `Java build path` screen. And be sure to make the distinction between `.java` and `.class` files.

Comment: I've added that class folder, but how do I reference it? How do I import it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between folder and source folder. Right-click the folder and use `Build Path/Use as Source Folder` menu option.